# Wick's rotation for the harmonic oscillator. Explicit computation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

I'm stuck in this computation; it shouldn' be difficult but it's always better to check with a lot of details these things. Consider the propagator for the harmonic oscillator [Ashok p.55 bottom of the page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812568476)

$$
\int \mathcal{D}\eta \, \exp \left(-\frac{i m}{2\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt \eta(t)(\frac{d^2}{dt^2} + w^2)\eta(t) \right) \,. \tag{4.5}
$$

The Wick rotation amounts to replace $$t\rightarrow t'=-i\tau.\tag{4.6}$$ Regarding the integration in the exponent:

1. Is this a physicist's name to make the integration
   $$
   -\frac{im}{2\hbar}\oint dz \eta(z) \left(\frac{d^2}{dz^2} + w^2 \right)\eta(t), \tag{1}
   $$
   along a closed path that does not contain poles?
2. If this is the case, then doing the integration over the imaginary axis $z=it'$ ($t'_i<t'_f$) should be, with $dz=idt'$, $d^2/dz^2=-d^2/dt'^2$
   $$
   =-\frac{m}{2\hbar}\int_{it_i}^{it_f}dt'\eta(it') \left(-\frac{d^2}{dt'^2}+w^2 \right)\eta(it'),\tag{2}
   $$
   where the minus sign in the front of the equation comes from the fact that I am doing the integration in the counter clockwise direction and the interior of the circuit is to the right.

Now somewhere in this reasoning I have screwed up, because the result should read

$$
\frac{-m}{2\hbar}\int_{\tau_i}^{\tau_f}d\tau \, \eta (\tau)\left(-\frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}+w^2 \right)\eta(\tau),\tag{4.7}
$$

where $t'=-i\tau$. Between my result and the one in the book, I don't see why $d^2/dt'^2=d^2/d\tau^2$.

Can someone point out where the mistake was done?

Comment: Comment to the post (v5): It is confusing that OP & Das use the same notation $t^{\prime}$ for different quantities. Consider to use another notation, say $\tilde{t}$, for one of them.

Comment: $dt'=-idT \to dt'^2 = - (i*i)dT^2 \to dt'^2 = dT^2$ taking inverse from both side (mathematically speaking it's not rigorous at all but it's the easy way) gives $d^2/dt'^2=d^2/dT^2$ and also $it'=T$ so I can't see any difference between two last equations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, if $t'=-iT$, then $dt'=-idT$, so this will add up a $-i$ to the front of the equation, which does not have (4.7).